# ASP.NET 4.0 Custom IHttpModule doesn't fire when call WebMethod with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, .net-4.0, webmethod, httpmodule

I'm googling a lot to find a solution to my problem, but I've not found it yet.

I'm migrating a Web Application from .NET framework 3.5 to 4.0 that makes extensive use of method marked as **[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]** called via **jQuery $.ajax()**.
Furthermore, I have a custom **HttpModule** to fill the **CurrentPrincipal** with user information received from http header variables.
Morever, the application based on .net 3.5 is deployed on IIS 7.0 with Integrated Mode application pool and have the following configuration about custom modules:

```
<modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule" />          
      <add name="MyHttpModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="MyNamespace.MyHttpModule, MynameSpace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</modules>
```

and

```
<httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="MyHttpModule" type="MyNamespace.MyHttpModule, MynameSpace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</httpModules>
```

**The application based on .NET 3.5 framework works fine and for all requests the custom HttpModule was always called, both from standard .net GET/POST and AJAX GET/POST calls.**

Now, on the migrated Web Application, based on .net 4.0 framework, I left the same configuration (upgrating version from 3.5.0.0 to 4.0.0.0) but it doesn't work.
The web server is the same, with IIS 7.0 and application pool with Integrated Mode.
The custom HttpModule is called on the first request for the home page, but not for the WebMethod requests.
I also tried to revers module order with no effect.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You left same configuration, don't you change version of script module to .net 4.0.0.0 instead of 3.5.0.0 . as  <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/> ?

Comment: I changed the version of assembly from 3.5.0.0 to 4.0.0.0 as mentioned

Comment: Do you also use ajax control toolkit from .net 3.5? May be you go on version 4 also. If you don't use ajax control toolkit then you may trying removing ScriptModule.

Comment: I don't use Ajax Control Toolkit. I use jQuery to call web method via Ajax technology.

Comment: @NicolaCeliento I am facing the same issue, any solution you found for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Answer (score 1):

5 years later, I'm having the same issue.  I had a bunch of `[WebMethod]` attributes in an `.aspx` file, and moving them out into separate `.asmx` files did the trick for me.